# How to achieve ListView smooth scrolling in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created a list view with network images and when I am trying to scroll the listview it's scrolling is not smooths it feels like jerking. For caching I have used cached_network_image: any, this library itself working fine but listview is not getting scrolled smooth.

I know we can achieve this with Future widget but dont know how to return cached image with future.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

void main() {
   runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        title: 'List view with network images',
        home: ListViewController(),

     )
  );
}


class ListViewController extends StatelessWidget {

var imagesArray = [
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550484786.jpeg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550218043.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550217808.jpeg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550111913.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550108862.jpeg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550024618.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550022739.jpeg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549935759.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549935073.jpeg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549850545.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549849978.jpeg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549008412.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548985261.jpeg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548821873.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548731040.jpeg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548641672.jpeg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548410089.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547774905.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547701178.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547625318.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547624883.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547619153.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547606341.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547606200.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547603338.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547602464.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547454842.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547192524.jpg",
  "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547191374.jpg"
];




Widget _imageCell(String imageUrl) {

return ListTile(
  leading: CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: imageUrl, placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(), errorWidget: Icon(Icons.error),),
);

}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return Material(
  child: ListView.separated(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return _imageCell(imagesArray[index]);
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      itemCount: imagesArray.length),
);
}



}
```

Edit: After changing build configuration to Release still same, jerking.

Comment: check the app in release mode.

Comment: yes debug mode is not smooth make it --profile or even --release

Answer (score 18, accepted):

2 things

- consider using `FadeInImage.memoryNetwork` instead of `cached_network_image`, and/or
- consider using `ListView(children: List<Widget> )` instead of `ListView.separated(itemBuilder: )`

### `FadeInImage.memoryNetwork`

Ref https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images

When running your example code, I can't help to notice that `cached_network_image` doing some image rescaling/sampling affecting main UI thread, it's likely that this package is doing computational-heavy task on main thread. Using the official cooking book yields better result for me (Android emulator), full sample code (you may want to change `kTransparentImage` to some other loading icon)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'List view with network images',
    home: ListViewController(),
  ));
}

class ListViewController extends StatelessWidget {
  var imagesArray = [
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550484786.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550218043.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550217808.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550111913.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550108862.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550024618.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550022739.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549935759.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549935073.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549850545.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549849978.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549008412.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548985261.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548821873.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548731040.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548641672.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548410089.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547774905.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547701178.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547625318.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547624883.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547619153.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547606341.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547606200.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547603338.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547602464.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547454842.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547192524.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547191374.jpg"
  ];

  Widget _imageCell(String imageUrl) {
    return ListTile(
        leading: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
      placeholder: kTransparentImage,
      image: imageUrl,
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
    return Material(
      child: 
      ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return _imageCell(imagesArray[index]);
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
          itemCount: imagesArray.length),
    );
  }
}
```

### `ListView(children: List<Widget> )`

Ref https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Secondly, if you know in advance that you are going to have this finite not-so-long list, maybe you want to use `ListView(children: List<Widget> )` instead of `ListView.separated(itemBuilder: )`, because `itemBuilder` will invoke/call the functions more often, and right now images are cached (either by `FadeInImage.memoryNetwork` or `cached_network_image`) for full content only, **not for thumbnail**, @user1462442 mention source image size, and I agree with that assessment. What we can do is to reduce the invocation to a number as low as possible.

E.g code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'List view with network images',
    home: ListViewController(),
  ));
}

class ListViewController extends StatelessWidget {
  var imagesArray = [
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550484786.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550218043.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550217808.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550111913.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550108862.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550024618.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1550022739.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549935759.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549935073.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549850545.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549849978.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1549008412.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548985261.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548821873.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548731040.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548641672.jpeg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1548410089.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547774905.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547701178.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547625318.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547624883.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547619153.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547606341.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547606200.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547603338.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547602464.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547454842.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547192524.jpg",
    "http://iastro.shangcarts.com/pub/media/notice/File-1547191374.jpg"
  ];

  Widget _imageCell(String imageUrl) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: Icon(Icons.error),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
    return Material(
      child: ListView(
        children: imagesArray.map((imageUrl) => _imageCell(imageUrl)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As said, you can apply both of these recommendations as well.

Comment: I went the ListView/children route since my list was likewise "small". Fixed.

Comment: It doesn't seem that FadeInImage.memoryNetwork caches the image. If you close the app and reopen the image will be loaded from network again, while in CachedImageNetwork the image will be loaded immediately form cache. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: Not true for ListView. From docs "The ListView.builder constructor takes an IndexedWidgetBuilder, which builds the children on demand. This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible." https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Comment: @RoddyR what statement in the answer above is not true and/or conflicting with the reference you quote? I think you assume the answer implies "ListView.builder [...] builds the children immediately", which it definitely not.The answer implies "ListView.builder [...] has much less invocation in comparison to   ListView.separated(itemBuilder: )"

Answer (score 5):

I was also looking at it for a month and after a lot of research I found a single line code that makes a listview or any list a buttery smooth scrolling

Just use **physics** property as `physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),` and feel the difference

also if you want it for a **Column** you can use **Singlechildscrollview** and in that, you can use the physics property.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your listview:

```
 physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

If you are testing on an emulator, I suggest to build the release APK, install the APK on your Android phone and check to see if it is still jerky. Emulator are resource hogging, so it might be a cause.

Lastly, you can try to reduce the image numbers, image types or size to see if it is still laggy.

Else report this issue at github, so that the flutter team is aware.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a good solution right now other than reduce the source image size. I took a look at your image list and some the images are quite huge.

https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/90

https://github.com/pejalo/flutter_image_performance

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25469

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27625#issuecomment-461677587

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2848

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26194

Flutter downscaling is quite slow. Flutter team have to optimize it for performance.

Another thing, your code does not run on flutter stable

```
Flutter 1.0.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5391447fae (3 months ago) • 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
Engine • revision 7375a0f414
Tools • Dart 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:56:64: Error: The argument type '#lib1::CircularProgressIndicator'
can't be assigned to the parameter type '(#lib2::BuildContext, dart.core::String)
→ #lib2::Widget'.
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to
'(#lib2::BuildContext, dart.core::String) → #lib2::Widget'.
  leading: CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: imageUrl, placeholder:
  CircularProgressIndicator(), errorWidget: Icon(Icons.error),),
                                                               ^
lib/main.dart:56:106: Error: The argument type '#lib1::Icon' can't be assigned to
the parameter type '(#lib2::BuildContext, dart.core::String, dart.core::Exception)
→ #lib2::Widget'.
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to
'(#lib2::BuildContext, dart.core::String, dart.core::Exception) → #lib2::Widget'.
  leading: CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: imageUrl, placeholder:
  CircularProgressIndicator(), errorWidget: Icon(Icons.error),),
                                                                                                         ^
Compiler failed on /Users/blah/stackoverflow/issue_54786567/lib/main.dart
Error launching application on iPhone XR.


flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Starting Xcode build...                                          
 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                    3.9s

 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                  3.4s

Xcode build done.                                            9.1s
 5.8s
Syncing files to device iPhone XR...                             
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
flutter: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
flutter: These invalid constraints were provided to RenderSemanticsAnnotations's layout() function by the
flutter: following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
flutter:   RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:258:13)
flutter: The offending constraints were:
flutter:   BoxConstraints(w=382.0, h=Infinity)
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure>.throwError (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:504:9)
flutter: #1      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:547:21)
flutter: #2      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:551:6)
flutter: #3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1549:24)
flutter: #4      RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:258:13)
flutter: #5      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #6      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #8      RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
flutter: #9      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #10     _RenderListTile._layoutBox (package:flutter/src/material/list_tile.dart:892:9)
flutter: #11     _RenderListTile.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/list_tile.dart:913:30)
flutter: #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #13     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:199:11)
flutter: #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #15     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #17     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #19     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #21     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #23     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #25     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:164:27)
flutter: #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #27     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:182:11)
flutter: #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #29     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:405:13)
flutter: #30     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1316:12)
flutter: #31     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1234:20)
flutter: #32     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1509:7)
flutter: #33     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:768:18)
flutter: #34     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:281:19)
flutter: #35     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:677:13)
flutter: #36     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:219:5)
flutter: #37     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
flutter: #38     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
flutter: #39     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5)
flutter: #40     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:13)
flutter: #41     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:143:3)
flutter:
flutter: The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
flutter:   RenderConstrainedBox#57507 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:   creator: ConstrainedBox ← Container ← FadeTransition ← Stack ← StreamBuilder<FileInfo>-[#fb1e3] ←
flutter:   CachedNetworkImage ← IconTheme ← Builder ← _ListTile ← MediaQuery ← Padding ← SafeArea ← ⋯
flutter:   parentData: <none> (can use size)
flutter:   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=382.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
flutter:   size: MISSING
flutter:   additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(biggest)
flutter: This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
flutter:   RenderSemanticsAnnotations#494da NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:     RenderImage#98201 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#57507 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#ac73c relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#95164 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#9efb3 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#16fcc relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
```

I have to make a few modifications.